# Why do I get a 'context is incorrect' error when trying to use Python `bpy.ops.nla.tracks.add()`with the NLA?

Tags: python, scripting, nla-editor

I am trying to use `bpy.ops.nla.tracks.add()` but I get this error:

[image: The detail can be got in the image which is achieved through the screenshots]

Comment: You can also do this with low level methods https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.NlaTracks.html#bpy.types.NlaTracks ... perhaps change your q to how to add tracks to NLA using python for both context override etc and low lev methods.

Comment: But I also want yo  use the function ' Add transition'  in the menu bar with the methods 'bpy.ops.nla.transition_add()' which also has the same error.